# How Elasticsearch multi matching with _all work?

Tags: elasticsearch

I wanted to know how multi matching with _all work. Let's say I have the following query:

```
"multi_match": {
                                    "query": x,
                                     "type": "phrase",
                                     "fields":"_all",   
                                 }
```

Does it search all available fields for the particular phrase and returns a record if the phrase exists in all fields? What if some of the fields have it and some other do not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_all` field is just field which concatenate all your fields into one big string and then analyze it in standard way - if no defined using standard analyzer for text. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html

It's possible to remove some fields from _all fields while defining your mapping with param 'include_in_all' https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/include-in-all.html

So does it make sense to use phrase query on concatenation of your all fields? Rather not. I would say that multi_match can let you achieve similar goals as _all fields; you can search multiple fields in one query. But when using _all fields you can just use 'match' query.

Answer (score 1):

_all field (which is removed in 6.0) index all the values from your json document whatever the field they appeared in.

Comment: Thanks @dadoonet for your comment. But why when I use the same query with only specifying 2 fields the number of records that I get is more than the number of records when I do _all? for example if I use _all i get 100 records back, but when I use "fields":["title", "description"]  I get 101 records and only 86 records among them is duplicated!